# RecyclerView not reading property to assign values

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm trying to get my RecyclerView adapter to obtain values from an Array in my fragment but for some reason is doesn't work and I get this error (I think I have gotten lost somewhere):

> `lateinit property dataTitles has not been initialized`

What's the correct way to obtain the data in this scenario?

**Fragment class**

```
class MyFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {
    private lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rv, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val v = view

        val dataTitles: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
        val dataSubtitles: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

        mRecyclerView = v!!.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.my_recyclerview)

        // Set the linear layout manager
        mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        // create the adapter
        val mAdapter = MyRVAdapter()


        // init data
        dataTitles.add(getString(R.string.addition))
        dataTitles.add(getString(R.string.subtraction))
        dataTitles.add(getString(R.string.multiplication))
        dataTitles.add(getString(R.string.division))

        dataSubtitles.add(getString(R.string.addition_information))
        dataSubtitles.add(getString(R.string.subtraction_information))
        dataSubtitles.add(getString(R.string.multiplication_information))
        dataSubtitles.add(getString(R.string.division_information))

        // Set the adapter
        mRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

**Adapter class**

```
class MyRVAdapter(private val dataTitles: Array<String>, private val dataSubtitles: Array<String>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRVAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    private val typeItem = 1
    private val typeHeader = 2
    private val typeGrid = 3

    private val primeNumbers = arrayOf("2", "3", "5", "7", "11", "13",
            "17", "19", "23")


    private lateinit var adapterGV: MyAdapter

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, type: Int): MyRVAdapter.MyViewHolder {
        return when (type) {
            typeHeader -> MyRVAdapter.MyViewHolder(inflateHelper(R.layout.rv_header, parent))

            typeItem -> MyRVAdapter.MyViewHolder(inflateHelper(R.layout.rv_item, parent))

            typeGrid -> MyRVAdapter.MyViewHolder(inflateHelper(R.layout.rv_gv, parent))

            else -> MyRVAdapter.MyViewHolder(inflateHelper(R.layout.rv_item, parent))
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: MyRVAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val llGV = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_gv)

        val llTV = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_tv)

        val mGridView = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<GridView>(R.id.my_gv)


        when (getItemViewType(position)) {
            typeHeader -> {
                val tValueE = TypedValue()
                // test
                llTV.context.theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.imgUnfoldMore, tValueE, true)

                val tValueC = TypedValue()
                // test
                llTV.context.theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.imgUnfoldLess, tValueC, true)
            }
            typeGrid -> {
                val titleG = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_gv_A)
                titleG.setText(R.string.prime_numbers)

                //
                val cardViewGV = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.cv_gv)
                val mLinearLayoutGV = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.cardview_gv_titlerow

                mGridViewA.isEnabled = false
                mGridViewA.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = false
//                adapterGV = MyAdapter(activity!!.applicationContext, 0)
                mGridViewA.adapter = adapterGV
                for (ldnBusesRoute in ldnBusesRoutes) {
                    adapterGV.addAdapterItem(AdapterItem(ldnBusesRoute))
                }
                typeItem -> {
                    // get the current item
                    val itemA = dataTitles[position - 2]
                    val itemB = dataSubtitles[position - 2]

                    //
                    val txtTitle = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_title)
                    txtTitle.text = itemA

                    val txtSubtitle = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_subtitle)
                    txtSubtitle.text = itemB
            }
        }
    }

    private fun inflateHelper(resId: Int, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        return LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(resId, parent, false)
    }

    // inner class for view holder to use,
    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)


    // Adapter for GridView
    private inner class MyAdapter internal constructor(context: Context, textviewid: Int) : ArrayAdapter<AdapterItem>(context, textviewid) {
        private val items = ArrayList<AdapterItem>()

        internal fun addAdapterItem(item: AdapterItem) {
            items.add(item)
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return items.size
        }

        override fun getItem(position: Int): AdapterItem? {
            return items[position]
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }

        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
            val rowView: View = when (convertView) {

                null -> LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false)
//                    activity!!.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false)
                else -> convertView
            }

            val tv = rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_gridview) as TextView
            tv.text = items[position].first

            return rowView
        }
    }

    internal inner class AdapterItem // add more items
    (var first: String)

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataTitles.size + 2
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> typeHeader
            1 -> typeGrid
            else -> typeItem
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error is pretty straightforward: you're not initializing `dataTitles`. When you label a variable with `lateinit`, Kotlin expects you to initialize it later. It's a way to avoid having to declare the variable as nullable.

To initialize it, you can do something like:

```
private val mutableList = mutableListOf<String>()
```

And you're doing the same with `dataSubtitles`.

Comment: Notice how I used `val dataTitles: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()` and `val dataSubtitles: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()`. Is there a way that I can access the `dataTitles` and `dataSubtitles` values from the adapter?

Comment: `dataTitles` and `dataSubtitles` are private in `MyRVAdapter`, and they're declared as `lateinit` properties. So you have to initialize those two. The ones you declare and initialize in the Fragment are different variables with the same name.

Comment: Why do you want to access those values on the Fragment? You can send your data straight through the adapter's consctructor. You can get a gist of the basics here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: That's what I meant! I've already read that but it's not showing any values from the data set. Do I need to use something like `class MyRVAdapter(private val dataTitles: Array<String>, private val dataSubtitles: Array<String>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRVAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {...`?

Comment: You need to pass the data into the adapter somehow. Passing it through the constructor is the most common and safe way to do it, AFAIK.